# Intermittent invalid MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'xxx.yyy in 'field list' - Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

There are several hundred questions containing the unknown column error, but after looking at dozens, none are the same as my problem. They all seem to be actually errors in the select statement, but in my case the select statement a) sometimes works from the servelt, b) consistently works from PHP, c) consistently works from the Squirrel SQL client.

I have a legacy system and no control over the queries. The queries have worked fine from PHP mysql for years. This error is intermittent.

For example, all of the reports were working correctly last night. This morning I tried the service again and some of the queries failed with the MySQLSyntaxErrorException from the Tomcat server (Linux Centos, Java 1.6, Tomcat 6). I copied a copy of the war file into Tomcat's webapp directory to cause Tomcat to reload the servlet, and the query worked correctly again. The MySQL server, on a different host, is 5.0.17 on Centos 5.

More details: yesterday it seemed to occur when Tomcat had been idle for a while - when I came back to the application after a couple of hours the very complicated queries suffered this error for a time. The application has a lot of less complicated queries that worked - I ran these a few times then suddenly the complicated queries started working. This happened three or four times yesterday. But as a counter example, the complicated query worked the first time this morning. It is also happening in Tomcat 5.5.

There are no messages in the mysql server logs; I can't turn on warnings at the moment though I did increase the maximum packet length.

Also, this query was failing consistently with mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar but the working correctly intermittently started when I downgraded to mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar. Copying the query into the Squirrel SQL client on windows results in it working correctly.

The servlet is using Apache POI to use the results of this query to make a spreadsheet.

Is there a known problem with this combination of software?

NEW INFORMATION **

It isn't to do with the length of the query. Here is a short example with the statement, the stack trace and the table definition with names changed to protect the innocent; please note that the servlet succeeds some of the time and the query works fine when pasted into Squirrel SQL. There are no other messages or warnings on either the client or server side. There are also similar queries that consistently work 100% of the time.

Query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS aa_bbb_cccc.id, aa_bbb_cccc.user_id, aa_bbb_cccc.user, aa_bbb_cccc.state, aa_bbb_cccc.time_stamp, aa_bbb_cccc.c20, aa_bbb_cccc.c12, aa_bbb_cccc.c21, aa_bbb_cccc.c22, aa_bbb_cccc.c23, aa_bbb_cccc.c13, aa_bbb_cccc.c15, aa_bbb_cccc.c14, aa_bbb_cccc.c16, aa_bbb_cccc.c13b, aa_bbb_cccc.c13c FROM aa_bbb_cccc WHERE 1=1
```

Stack Trace

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'aa_bbb_cccc.c21' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2678)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1612)
        ...
```

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `aa_bbb_cccc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `c20` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c12` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c13` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c15` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c14` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c16` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c13b` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `xx_yy` int(11) default NULL,
  `c13c` text,
  `key2` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `c21` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c22` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `c23` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`key2`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `time_stamp` (`time_stamp`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Could you send the query you are using ?

Comment: He said he isn't allowed to show the query. Do you have access to the MySQL server logs? You may want to turn on the general query log and turn on all warning options. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: Turns out that it has nothing to do with JDBC (even though it's not solved yet). The same problem occurs with the mysql command line client from the tomcat server. The query runs fine locally and on with a JDBC client on a different host.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet you are losing packets.  Take a look in your server logs or network devices and see if packets are being dropped or problematic.

Comment: Any idea what `Exception` is thrown by the `JDBC` driver if `max_allowed_packet` is exceeded? If it's only failing on the query some times, it could be that the longer arguments in those cases cause this size to be exceeded. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: The manual states that this error would cause the connection to be closed. This is not happening - all we are getting is the Syntax Exception with the invalid column message.